# How to plot rank vs count using the list generated with "Counter"

Tags: python, counter, rank

I am very new to coding, I am trying to first use the list generated by the counter to make a plot which is the rank of the word vs the count.
The first question I have is how to access those values. most_frequent(white_token)[0] gives me ('the', 26423), but how to access the value 26423, which should be used for ranking I guess? (solved)
Second question is that this counter command seems already rank based on the frequency of the words.. but how can I extract this information for example how I get 3 for the rank of the word "to"

I apprciate yoour help!
the image shows the result of counter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oBVb.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

based on this:

```
" most_frequent(white_token)[0] gives me ('the', 26423), but how to access the value 26423 "
```

if

```
most_frequent(white_token)[0]
```

return this:

```
('the', 26423)
```

then when you use " most_frequent(white_token)[0] " it returns a tuple. To index a tuple, you index it like you would a list.

for example:

```
most_frequent(white_token)[0]
# returns ('the', 26423)

most_frequent(white_token)[0][0]
# returns 'the'

most_frequent(white_token)[0][1]
# returns 26423
```

Answer (score 0):

The data type of the `most_frequent` is a `list` and the returned result is a `tuple`.
To access the tuple you need to do it the following way:

```
most_frequent(white_token)[0][0]
# Output
'the'

most_frequent(white_token)[0][1]
# Output
26423
```